# Nested mat-expansion-panel's not closing as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the mat-expansion-panel and providing dynamically content in the body using ng-content. There are cases where the component is being used twice or more times.

component JS:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'noah-collapse',
    templateUrl: './collapse.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./collapse.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

})
export class CollapseComponent {
    @Input() title: string = '';
    @Input() expanded: boolean = true;
    @Input() size: TitleSizes = 'medium';
}

type TitleSizes = 'large' | 'medium';
```

reusable component HTML:

```
<mat-expansion-panel
        [expanded]="expanded">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            {{title}}
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

usage of reusable component

```
<collapse [title]="something">
            Some Content
            <div *ngIf="something.length">
                <collapse [title]="something from nested collapse">
                  Some Content from nested collapse
                </collapse>
            </div>
</collapse>
```

visual expanded: =================================================
[image]

visual collapsed: ================================================
[image]

when the parent collapse element is set to false the child is still visible and overflowing on the bellow element, any idea how to solve this ?